# NodeJS MongoDB adapter interprets string as literal instead of value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
var keyExp = 'experienceCat' + req.param('category');
User.native(function(err,collection)
{
    collection.find({'_id':{$in:usersArray}},{fields:{'name':1,'avatar':1,'fbId':1,'country':1,keyExp:1}}).toArray(function (err,userProfiles)
    {
        res.send(userProfiles);
    });
});
```

The problem is that instead of changing the keyExp to its current value (which should be `"experienceCat0"` for example) it's actually trying to find the column with the name `"keyExp"` which of course doesn't exist.

How should the code look like to be able to read the correct column based on the `req.param('category')` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should do it today:

```
var fields = {'name':1,'avatar':1,'fbId':1,'country':1};
fields['experienceCat' + req.param('category')] = 1;
User.native(function(err,collection){
    collection.find({'_id':{$in:usersArray}},{fields:fields}).toArray(function (err,userProfiles)
    {
        res.send(userProfiles);
    });
});
```

With ES6 [you'll be able to express that in a more concise way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6):

```
var keyExp = 'experienceCat' + req.param('category');
User.native(function(err,collection){
    collection.find( ... ,'fbId':1,'country':1,[keyExp]:1}}).toArray(function (err,userProfiles)
                                               ^^^^^^^^
    {
        res.send(userProfiles);
    });
});
```